# What is difference of & used inside scss class on pseudo class?

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-class

what is the difference between these two scss implementations?

```
.button {
    :hover{
    }
}

.button {
    &:hover{
    }
}
```

which one is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common uses for `&` in  Sass is `pseudo class selectors`. These include the `:hover`, `:active`, and `:focus` found accompanying selectors like `<a>` and `<input>`.

In your example, This is the correct syntax in scss

```
.button {
    &:hover{
    }
}
```

And in CSS it is converted to

```
.button:hover{
}
```

And the 2nd one, This one is not correct.

```
.button {
    :hover{
    }
}
```

This is converted to:

```
.button :hover{
}
```

which is not what we had used it for

Comment: This does point to a selector. But for that, the `<button>` element needs to have child elements, eg., `<span>` could be a valid one. Technically `button :hover` is similar to `button *:hover`. And if there's a span inside the button, it'll be targeted. Just telling! 

Answer (score 0):

The `&` is an extremely useful feature in Sass (and Less). It’s used when nesting. It can be a nice time-saver when you know how to use it, or a bit of a time-waster when you’re struggling and could have written the same code in regular CSS.

Let's consider a basic nesting:

```
.parent {
  .child {}
}
```

This compiles to:

```css
.parent .child {}
```

The `&` comes in handy when you’re nesting and you want to create a more specific selector, like an element that has *both* of two classes, like this:

```css
.some-class.another-class { }
```

You can do this while nesting by using the `&`.

```
.some-class {
  &.another-class {}
}
```

---

The `&` in the SCSS is for removing the hierarchy. The space makes a huge difference. The space will make it to look for child element's `:hover` state rather than the `button`'s `:hover` state.

In your case, if you have this way:

```
.button {
  :hover{
  }
}

.button {
  &:hover{
  }
}
```

The output will be:

```css
.button {
}
.button :hover {
}

.button {
}
.button:hover {
}
```

You can check these out in [SassMeister - The Sass Playground!](https://www.sassmeister.com/).